# I'm inexperienced with HTML and don't understand why my buttons don't follow my CSS

Tags: html, css

My goals for the buttons: 
- When a user hovers their mouse over the button, it will darken.
- The buttons will link to different html files in the same folder as my index.html

My codes is as follows:

```css
body {
  background-image: url("res/images/space2.jpg");
}

div.wrapper {
  width: 720px;
  height: 576px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

div.banner {
  width: 750px;
  height: 160px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

div.topnav {
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #03023a;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 700px;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
}

.button {
  background-color: #050462;
  border: none;
  color: blue;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button1 {
  background-color: #0a07ab;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #07057a;
}

.button1:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.button2 {
  background-color: #0a07ab;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #07057a;
}

.button2:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.button3 {
  background-color: #0a07ab;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #07057a;
}

.button3:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #ffffff;
}

div.maindiv {
  width: 750px;
  height: 97px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

div.main {
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: url(res/images/space.jpg);
  background-position: left top;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 700px;
  height: 3000px;
  text-align: center;
}

p.welcome {
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  text-indent: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="banner">
    <center>
      <img src="res/images/topbanlogo.png" />
    </center>
  </div>
  <div class="topnav">
    <center>
      <button class="button button1"><a href=
          "index.html"><font color="white">Home</font></a></button>
      <button class="button button2"><a href=
          "downloads.html"><font color="white">Downloads</font>
          <button class="button button3"><a href=
          "downloads.html"></a><a href=
          "downloads.html"></a><a href="uploads.html"><font color=
          "white">Uploads</font></a></button></a>
      </button>
    </center>
  </div>
  <div class="maindiv"></div>
  <div class="main">
    <p class="welcome"></p>
    <center>
      <h1>
        <font face="arial" color="white">Easy and simple file downloads.
        </font>
      </h1>
    </center>
    <p class="main"></p>
    <center>
      <p>
        <font face="arial" color="white">At Kylosting, we strive to provide the easiest file hosting in the Blockland realm.
        </font>
      </p>
      <p>
        <font face="arial" color="white">
          <font face="arial" color="white">ph</font>
        </font>
      </p>
      <p>
        <font face="arial" color="white">
          <font face="arial" color="white">ph</font>
        </font>
      </p>
      <p>
        <font face="arial" color="white">
          <font face="arial" color="white">ph</font>
        </font>
      </p>
    </center>
  </div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

As mentioned, I'm inexperienced in HTML and basing my code off of online examples, so there's probably some noob mistake that I've made.

Comment: fyi, `<font>` and `<center>` tags are deprecated. You should think about removing them

Comment: "_When a user hovers their mouse over the button, it will darken_" But all of your `hover` selectors make both the font and background white `.button1:hover { background-color:#ffffff;  color:#ffffff; }`.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Your buttons work fine your `#mainDiv` is covering up your `#topNav` so it is impossible to hover over the buttons.  You may want to set the z-index of your topnav to 1 or 2 like the following:

```
div.topnav{
    border-radius:25px;
    background:#03023a;
    padding:20px;
    width:700px;
    height:50px;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:2;
}
```

there are many other issues here you may want to read up on your positioning as well but the buttons work fine its just that they are covered up at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

To get your `:hover` states to work, simply add a `z-index` value to your fixed `.topnav` because it's being cover by `#myDiv` and needs a higher stack index to recognize your hover.

```
div.topnav{
     border-radius:25px;
     background:#03023a;
     padding:20px;
     width:700px;
     height:50px;
     position:fixed;
     z-index: 1; /*Added*/
}
```

```html
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <link rel="icon" href="res/images/favicon.ico" />
    <title>
      Kylosting
    </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
/*<![CDATA[*/
                        body{
                                background-image: url("res/images/space2.jpg");
                        }
                        div.wrapper{
                                width:720px;
                                height:576px;
                                margin-left:auto;
                                margin-right:auto;
                        }
                        div.banner{
                                width:750px;
                                height:160px;
                                position:relative;
                                top:0px;
                                margin-left:auto;
                                margin-right:auto;
                        }
                        div.topnav{
                                border-radius:25px;
                                background:#03023a;
                                padding:20px;
                                width:700px;
                                height:50px;
                                position:fixed;
                                z-index: 1;
                                top: 20px;
                        }
                        .button{
                                background-color:#050462;
                                border:none;
                                color:blue;
                                padding:16px 32px;
                                text-align:center;
                                text-decoration:none;
                                display:inline-block;
                                font-size:16px;
                                margin:4px 2px;
                                -webkit-transition-duration:0.4s;
                                transition-duration:0.4s;
                                cursor:pointer;
                        }
                        .button1{
                                background-color:#0a07ab; 
                                color:black; 
                                border:2px solid #07057a;
                        }
                        .button1:hover{
                                background-color:#ffffff;
                                color:#ffffff;
                        }
                        .button2{
                                background-color:#0a07ab; 
                                color:black; 
                                border:2px solid #07057a;
                        }
                        .button2:hover{
                                background-color:#ffffff;
                                color:#ffffff;
                        }
                        .button3{
                                background-color:#0a07ab; 
                                color:black; 
                                border:2px solid #07057a;
                        }
                        .button3:hover{
                                background-color:#ffffff;
                                color:#ffffff;
                        }
                        div.maindiv{
                                width:750px;
                                height:97px;
                                position:relative;
                                top:0px;
                                margin-left:auto;
                                margin-right:auto;
                        }
                        div.main{
                                border-radius:25px;
                                background:url(res/images/space.jpg);
                                background-position: left top;
                                background-repeat: repeat;
                                padding:20px; 
                                width:700px;
                                height:3000px;
                                text-align:center;
                        }
                        p.welcome{
                                margin-left:15px;
                                margin-right:15px;
                                text-indent:16px;
                        }
    /*]]>*/
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="banner">
        <center>
          <img src="res/images/topbanlogo.png" />
        </center>
      </div>
      <div class="topnav">
        <center>
          <button class="button button1"><a href=
          "index.html"><font color="white">Home</font></a></button>
          <button class="button button2"><a href=
          "downloads.html"><font color="white">Downloads</font>
          <button class="button button3"><a href=
          "downloads.html"></a><a href=
          "downloads.html"></a><a href="uploads.html"><font color=
          "white">Uploads</font></a></button></a></button>
        </center>
      </div>
      <div class="maindiv"></div>
      <div class="main">
        <p class="welcome"></p>
        <center>
          <h1>
            <font face="arial" color="white">Easy and simple file
            downloads.</font>
          </h1>
        </center>
        <p class="main"></p>
        <center>
          <p>
            <font face="arial" color="white">At Kylosting, we strive to provide the
            easiest file hosting in the Blockland
            realm.</font>
          </p>
          <p>
            <font face="arial" color="white"><font face="arial"
            color="white">ph</font></font>
          </p>
          <p>
            <font face="arial" color="white"><font face="arial"
            color="white">ph</font></font>
          </p>
          <p>
            <font face="arial" color="white"><font face="arial"
            color="white">ph</font></font>
          </p>
        </center>
      </div>
      <div class="footer"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```